# Request from html client: how will I know that requested user is logged in or not?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-restcontroller

Here is my spring login handler

```
public class LoginSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        LoggedInUser logginUserObj = (LoggedInUser)authentication.getPrincipal();
        String userId = logginUserObj.getUserId();

        session.setAttribute("userId", userId);
        session.setAttribute("userName", logginUserObj.getName());
        session.setAttribute("hasPhoto", user.getProperty(UserVertex.profilePhotoUploaded.toString()));
        if(logginUserObj.getActivateLink()!=null)
            session.setAttribute("activateLink", logginUserObj.getActivateLink());

        try {
            Object referUrl = session.getAttribute("Referer_url");
            if(referUrl != null){
                session.removeAttribute("Referer_url");
                response.sendRedirect(referUrl.toString());
            }
            else
                response.sendRedirect("profile/"+userId);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error(ex);
        }
       }
    }
```

My client is in plain html, jQuery (in cordova). So my question is if everytime user makes a request, how will I know that requested user is logged in or not ?

e.g. here is a sample :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "addNewpost",
  data:{}
})
```

Here only a loggedin user can add new post. So when i am calling `addNewpost` rest service in spring `@RestController` how will i know that request is from logged in user ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a success handler so before the request goes to success handler it goes to authentication manager.In authentication manager if you have configured any authentication provider there authenticity of the user will be check and if it returns success then the call will go to onAuthenticationSuccess.In the authentication provider you actually look for some values in the request header depending upon the type of authentication provider you are using.If its missing then the user is not logged in.Here is a better picture with one example(Here its also checking authorization for admin) [image]

You can also refer to this [link](https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/spring-security-on-rest-api/)

Hope this gives you a clear picture!!

Comment: Let say i have `/api/edit/123` url now if a I am logged in user i must see `edit` link else `edit` link should not be shown. That how can achieve ?

Comment: @Manish simple way would be to set a authenticate service in the server on calling which server should return the role of the user (along with some other value ,if needed) .Keep the role in the session or some other method depending upon the front end technology then show the link accordingly to the user depedning upon  the user role

Comment: @Manish One more way would be to set the security filter of spring `<intercept-url pattern="/api/edit/*"
        access="hasRole('admin') "/>` and let the front-end call the API if the user is not authorized front-end will get error message.However in any case its better to have these  filter configured in the backend irrespective of frontend logic

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make sure that your web app returns 401 unauthorized when you are not logged in

Then with JQuery you use the error callback more or less as in following snippet, usually checking that `jqXHR.status` is 401 (unauthorized)

```
$.ajax({url:url, data:{}, error: function(jqXHR, e, x){
        alert("Error #" + jqXHR.status + "\n\n\t" + x );
    });
```

Whether the request is from a logged in user, in the server, depends on your security configuration, you should not check in the controller "manually" but just be sure that configuration declarations are correct.

BTW not sure if is the case to redirect to ANY url after login